# How do i include font awesome classes in my css file?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I can copy the fa classes from font awesome css but dont know how to copy data from **EOT and WOFF (font files)**. I am not using bootstrap. Just my html and css files. Please help.

Comment: You don't need to copy any data from the font files. Font awesome comes with a CSS file. Use that https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this inside of your CSS file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'your font name';
    src: url(path/to/your/font.woff);
}

.anyClassToUseFont {
    font-family: 'your font name'
}
```

Make sure the path to the `.woff` file is correct. Note, this will only work in some browsers, because not all support `.woff` file format. The other font files, (`.eot`, `.ttf`, etc) will help you cover others. For further information please consider looking into [CSS3 Font Face](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)

Comment: Thank you, its working like gem! Just one more concern, the WOFF file size is 70kb, is there any way i can reduce or extract just what i need from the font file?

Comment: 70kb isn't really a large filesize you should be concerned about. Most internet connections can load it in no time. thx @AndyM for editing my post :)

Comment: Np, Doml. However, I disagree about being concerned about 70kb. That is huge in terms of non-image assets. There are a lot of ways we can reduce it. Check out http://app.fontastic.me/. It is a service which lets you pick only the characters you want. The icon font for my own website is 6kb, and I have about 20 icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap fontawesome like this:

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This goes inside  `<head> </head>`  of your html.